# Why would someone, healthy and 10-39 years old, infected with covid-19 might die?

Tags: infection, virus, covid-19, death

From https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus we can see that a person between 10 and 39 years old has a probability of 0.2% of dying, which is very low but meaningful.

[image]

See also this table below for reference of deaths among healthy and unhealthy people

[image]

Why would that happen, what could possibly go wrong?

For example, can weight issues (below or above the average) affect this result?

My *question* is

- Why would someone, healthy and 10-39 years old, infected with covid-19 might die?

Comment: This chart does not necessarily show that any young and healthy people have died. We don't have a lot of information yet.

Comment: @BryanKrause why did they write 0.2% then ?

Comment: Do you think 100% of people 10-39 are healthy?

Comment: @BryanKrause nop. But hang on, I saw in another table where it said that 0.9% was the rate of death for healthy people

Comment: @user8473907, but that table doesn't distinguish between healthy 10-year-olds and healthy 90-year-olds.  To figure out if healthy young individuals are dying, you need a two-dimensional table that shows both age and health status.

Comment: @Mark where do I find the table?

Comment: @CareyGregory fair enough. I'm going to delete my comments. Btw may I know why is my question closed?

Comment: @user8473907 Because it's not clear what  you're asking. Are you asking why someone under 39 might die of this? It's unclear. Your question is salvageable, but you need to clarify what it is you're asking. And if you're just asking why some young people die while most don't then you need to do some more homework. I would start with researching the flu rather than COVID. The answers will be about the same.

Comment: @CareyGregory I meant the former question

Comment: @user8473907 I don't think the answer to why this virus is more deadly for older people rather than younger is known, but it's not very surprising that it is. That's a pretty typical pattern for many diseases and the reasons are fairly obvious. But I'll reopen the question and see if someone knows more about it.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you